# Files java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 5

Tags: java, regex, file

Hello I want to copy files without singles files or folders.

when i run the method i get a stack

```
public static void copyFiles() {
    String path = "C:\\luna\\trunk\\";
    List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(new File(path), new SuffixFileFilter("-4.7-SNAPSHOT.jar"), TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(C:\\luna\\trunk\\lunaRelease\\target\\lib\\)");
    for (File file : files) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(file.getName());
        if (file.getName().matches("warsztaty-4.7-SNAPSHOT.jar") || file.getName().matches("lunaRelease-4.7-SNAPSHOT.jar") || matcher.find() ) {
            System.out.println("Don't copy this file");
        } else {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            String source = file.getAbsolutePath();
            File sourcedir = new File(source);
            File dest = new File("C:\\library");
            try {
                FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(sourcedir, dest);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is stack when I run method.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 5
^(C:\luna\trunk\lunaRelease\target\lib\)
     ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1969)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.escape(Pattern.java:2485)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.atom(Pattern.java:2212)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2144)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:2010)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2919)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2065)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:2010)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1702)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1352)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
    at CopyFiles.copyFiles(CopyFiles.java:23)
    at CopyFiles.main(CopyFiles.java:17)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Try replacing \\ with \\\\.

Comment: Well, error message is not wrong, there is no `\l` special sequence in regex syntax, like for instance `\d` or `\w` `\s` so that ``\`` shouldn't probably be start of such sequence, so it should be escaped. Regex representing ``\``  may look like ``\\`` which can be written in string literal as `"\\\\"`. BUT why are you using regex in the first place? Why `matches("warsztaty-4.7-SNAPSHOT.jar")` instead of `equals("warsztaty-4.7-SNAPSHOT.jar")` (same about `lunaRelease-4.7-SNAPSHOT.jar).

Comment: Also if your only goal with regex is to use its start of line/data `^` anchor then you can achieve similar effect with `strData.startsWith(sequence)`

Comment: I resolve problem like this : file.getAbsolutePath().startsWith("C:\\luna\\trunk\\lunaRelease\\target\\lib\\")

Answer (score 0):

The new method , because I want to dont copy with path startwith : C:\luna\trunk\lunaRelease\target\lib\"

```
public static void copyFiles() {
    String path = "C:\\luna\\trunk\\";
    List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(new File(path), new SuffixFileFilter("-4.7-SNAPSHOT.jar"), TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.getName().matches("warsztaty-4.7-SNAPSHOT.jar") || file.getName().matches("lunaRelease-4.7-SNAPSHOT.jar") || file.getAbsolutePath().startsWith("C:\\luna\\trunk\\lunaRelease\\target\\lib\\") ) {
            System.out.println("Don't copy this file");
        } else {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            String source = file.getAbsolutePath();
            File sourcedir = new File(source);
            File dest = new File("C:\\library");
            try {
                FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(sourcedir, dest);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Note: `matcher` also uses regex and in regex dot `.` represents any character so `.matches("warsztaty-4.7-SNAPSHOT.jar")` would also return true for `.matches("warsztaty-4#7-SNAPSHOT#jar")`.

Comment: To check exact value use `equals` instead of `matches`.